# Two different values on a register, on the same instruction? (Cheat Engine)

Tags: cheat-engine

My situation is that I'm trying to find the send function of an online game. I found the buffer pointer and looked what accesses to it. It was obviously an instruction, which used the buffer pointer, but if I breakpoint on that instruction it doesn't contain the buffer ptr.
Why are the values different if I breakpoint?
First Picture: edx stores the adress of the buffer.
Second Picture: Breakpoint on that same exact instruction, but edx is not the same, which doesn't really make sense.

[image: edx stores the adress of the buffer]

[image: breakpoint on the same exact instruction]

Comment: Your question got a little confused, could you explain it to me again so I can correct your question and try to help you find your answer?

Comment: what is the instruction that you found and why do you think it's not accessing the buffer?

Comment: it's hard without pictures, so here my question including pictures: https://forum.cheatengine.org/viewtopic.php?p=5769983#5769983

Comment: You can add pictures to your question. Please try to put all information here so we don’t have to go somewhere else to find it.

Comment: This is totally normal, imagine this is a casual function, functions can be called with different parameters each time, so the addresses will be obviously different.